# Date range between date range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a SQL query where I have to find results which lies in a date range.

I have four params 
OEFrom (Saved in DB)
OETo (Save in DB)
To & From (User provided).

My query is some like

```
select * from tblName where OEFrom>=From and To>=OETo
```

The issue is this query works only when To and From lies between OEFrom and OETo.
If they lies outside it don't return results. FRom my understanding of it I have 4 cases:
*
 1. OEFrom>From and OEToFrom and OETo>To
 3. OEFromTo

Is there a way I can write query considering all these cases.

Comment: Using sql-server

Comment: Can you explain what you want? Post sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 1):

If you want any overlap, then use this logic:

```
select *
from tblName
where OEFrom <= To AND
      OETo >= From;
```

Two ranges overlap if each starts before the other ends (or in this case, on or before if you want to include the end points).

Comment: You mean to say select *
from tblName
where OEFrom <= From AND
      OETo >= To;

Comment: @SinghPiyush . . . No, I mean what I wrote.  Read the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check this-

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table
WHERE OEFrom BETWEEN [From] AND [To]  
AND OETo BETWEEN [From] AND [To]
```